# Save image/octet-stream, base64 encoded as image file via Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, canvg

I am using [canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) library to save google graph as image. More about this process can be found on this [page](http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html).

Ok, so JS framework provides me with encoded data of image and I POST that data using form and hidden field which triggers download.

HTML CODE

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="<%= rest_png_path %>" id="png_hidden" method="post">
  <input id="image_data_input" name="image_data" type="hidden" value="" />
  <input id="graph_container_div" type="hidden" value="gauge_div" />
  <input class="btn " name="commit" type="submit" value="Grafik" />
</form>
```

JS CODE

```
  $('#png_hidden').submit(function() {
    container_div = $('#graph_container_div').val();
    // saveAsImg method - returns image data base64 encoded.
    // in background there is this part of code
    // return imgData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    // I tried both version, with replace and without it
    data = saveAsImg(document.getElementById(container_div));
    $('#image_data_input').val(data);
    return true;
  });
```

Finally controller code which would response to POST request and trigger download is.

```
  def deliver_png
    #send_data ActiveSupport::Base64.decode64(params['image_data']),
    send_data params['image_data'],
      #:type =>'image/png',
      :type =>'image/png',
      :disposition => "attachment; filename=graf.png"
  end
```

As you can see I have played with few header options. Problem is downloaded image is corrupted. I opened it via HexEditor and I can see that it does not have PNG header but my knowledge of this is non existent. Hope you can help.

Comment: I know the reason (probably). But don't know the answer. I am struggling with the same issue. The thing is the return of the canvg function is a complete img element, not only the picture data.

Comment: Shouldn't form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: No it does not need to be enctype="multipart/form-data", the data is sent as a text field value not as a file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the page is submitting correct data to the server, the controller code should be as follows:

```
params['image_data'] =~ /^data:(\w+\/\w+);base64,(.*)/
mime_type= $1
img_base_64= $2

send_data ActiveSupport::Base64.decode64(img_base_64),
      :type =>'image/png',
      :disposition => "attachment; filename=graf.png"
```

You need to basically discard initial part that contains the mime type and string 'base64,'.

It will be worth while to check that there are no other errors in getting the base64 data in the Javascript. Please check, by changing the hidden field to a text field, that it is getting correct data.

BTW, I have also converted http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html to use jQuery, which makes it easier to maintain. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/kdeepak/3KTbJ/7/ and use this version if you are comfortable with jQuery.